# Can I restart service completely fresh in android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service

I am running background tasks via services and Async task inside of that. First of it takes all data from db and starts to run when users changes some options i destroy and start the service again to process new data but unfortunately service runs from where it stopped. so i want to start completely fresh service. I have tried `START_NOT_STICKY` but no use.

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();

    }
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
       Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
       process.execute();
       return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
    public void onDestroy() {
       stopSelf();
       super.onDestroy();
       Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    class ProcessImageAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {  
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
          // here im getting content from db and processing .
        if (isCancelled()) {
           System.exit(0);
        }
        }
    }

}
```

My activity code here is how i restart service

```
public void startServiceFucntion(int type){

        if(isMyServiceRunning(MyService.class)){
            if (type == 1){
                Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
                stopService(serviceIntent);
                startServiceFucntion(0);
            }
        } else {
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
            if(serviceReceiver == null){
                registerReceiver(serviceReceiver, intentSFilter);
            }
            startService(serviceIntent);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not stopping your service properly and your async task keeps on running in the background. You need to cancel your asynctask as well On destroy of your service.

Comment: Thank you buddy. I do not know how i missed it.

Comment: you welcome bro :) Sometimes It happens with me as well

Answer (score 1):

You don't stop service property.I think you can registered a broadcast in *AndroidManifest.xml* to restart service or destroy the service.

Comment: Thank you i did not stop async that was a problem

Answer (score 1):

> A service is a component that runs in the background to perform
>   long-running operations without needing to interact with the user and
>   it works even if application is destroyed.
>
> AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class
>   allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI
>   thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.

So You Can't stopping your **service** because your **AsyncTask** keeps on running .